# Show that the outer measure for $[a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is $|[a,b)|=b-a$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, outer-measure

> Show that the outer measure for $[a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ is $|[a,b)|=b-a$.

I can show that $|(a,b)|=|[a,b]|=b-a$, but I am not sure where to start with a half-open interval. I can assume there's an open cover $\mathcal{I}$ for $[a,b)$, but what next? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $[a,b)$ is Borel so its outer measure = its measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $$(a,b)\subseteq [a,b) \subseteq [a,b],$$ in conjunction with what you showed about $|(a,b)|=|[a,b]|$